# Security certificate - understanding CA role in code signing

Tags: java, cryptography, certificate, public-key-encryption, public-key

I'm a newbie to public cryptography. I have a clear understanding of it but I am confused over some issues which I couldn't figure out for the past 8 weeks. So I’ll try and explain as clear as I can in order to convey my confusion.

I'm trying to understand the role of CA public certificate and code signing and hence simulating this manually.

***Keystores***
acmesoft.jks (acting as a CA)
cindy.jks (employee of acmesoft)
me.jks (employee of acmesoft)

***Preliminary setup***
Acmesoft generates key-pairs and distribute its public key to employees (CA cert)
cindy imported CA cert to cindy.jks
me imported CA cert to me.jks

***Objectives***
me wants to jar some files, generate a certificate (ME cert), have acmesoft (CA) sign the certificate and sign the jar file to be sent to cindy

Here's my confusion.
In order to achieve the above objectives which process is the correct one?

***Process 1 in chronological order***
me generate key-pair (ME cert)
me jar a file (ME jar)
ME cert sent to CA (CA will sign with their private keys. ME signed_cert would have ME public key with CA private key signature)
me gives this ME signed_cert to cindy
cindy import ME signed_cert trusted cert without issue since cindy already imported CA certificate earlier
me signed the ME jar with ME private keys (not the ME signed_cert)
me give the ME jar file to cindy
cindy does a jarsigner verify on ME jar

***Process 1 issues***
Cindy keystore would have the ME signed_certs which consists of ME public key and CA signature. The jarsigner verification on the ME jar on cindy.jks shows no key found.

I expected it show key found since the ME signed_cert in cindy.jks has ME public key with CA private signature and the ME jar file is signed with ME private key.

***Process 2***
Exactly as process 1 but:
Me import the returned ME signed_certs from acmesoft (which consists of ME public key and CA signature) into ME jks
ME use jarsigner to sign the ME jar file

***Process 2 issues***
Upon signing, the jarsigner complaints the following:

jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: primary_root. primary_root must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.

Of course ME get the above error. ME.jks don't have the private keys of CA. ME not supposed to have CA private keys.

So I’m not sure how process 2 works. Is this right or my understanding is wrong.

Here are the actual keystores:

***acmesoft***

```
Alias name: acmeroot
Creation date: 2-Feb-2015
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=acmesoft, OU=information resources department, O=certificate authority, L=toronto, ST=ontario, C=ca
Issuer: CN=acmesoft, OU=information resources department, O=certificate authority, L=toronto, ST=ontario, C=ca
Serial number: 381e5a1f
Valid from: Mon Feb 02 00:01:14 EST 2015 until: Sun May 03 01:01:14 EDT 2015
Certificate fingerprints:
 MD5:  94:A1:76:2F:D5:05:8D:3C:2C:0F:B2:07:EC:9A:1E:12
 SHA1: AD:0A:28:AD:D9:42:C8:B3:C7:7D:CB:36:6F:EF:2C:99:50:00:30:3C
 SHA256: 31:14:A0:F8:51:72:37:7C:F5:25:6C:3A:F3:10:74:D8:F8:2B:B8:BC:FE:C7:F3:56:89:00:C4:6B:36:48:B2:A4
 Signature algorithm name: SHA1withDSA
 Version: 3
```

***ME keystore***

```
Alias name: ME
Creation date: 23-Jan-2015
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=kim yap, OU=rbss, O=cibc, L=toronto, ST=ontario, C=ca
Issuer: CN=kim yap, OU=rbss, O=cibc, L=toronto, ST=ontario, C=ca
Serial number: 4ecdc79c
Valid from: Fri Jan 23 11:10:12 EST 2015 until: Thu Apr 23 12:10:12 EDT 2015
Certificate fingerprints:
 MD5:  1A:FC:CF:40:4B:F7:1E:57:ED:28:1E:9B:5A:86:82:3E
 SHA1: 74:02:90:B5:DE:76:D4:04:21:23:2B:B8:6F:7C:B5:D4:41:5B:91:FB
 SHA256: B9:F6:A7:75:89:9F:0B:1F:29:DA:29:71:C1:18:1E:2D:BB:2F:35:41:4F:BA:D7:7C:50:CD:1A:CC:54:B7:12:37
 Signature algorithm name: SHA1withDSA
 Version: 3

Public Key: 02 81 80 79 14 21 28 57 EF 30 0D 98 0D 1A 8B EB 35 C3 76 06 0C FC DC D1 40 A6 0B 30 A4 F0 6E 24 AC 92 2D 44 F9 8F BB F9 51 6D 7F 99 F2 18 A4 55 2F D4 4A 1D 4F CC 9B 3D 5F 00 F6 95 58 77 E3 7E AD 2D 87 79 B7 9F BD 35 1D DC AF 7E 24 EC C7 09 20 C4 3D CA E6 5F 59 49 A9 00 DC 4B 06 CF 37 30 65 4E AC CB 80 50 F4 F4 21 8E DD 81 99 14 AA 9E 3A 07 C3 1B 2E 76 61 F9 B8 51 2A E0 A6 BA 55 0E DB 90 19
```

***cindy keystores***

```
Alias name: acmeroot
Creation date: 2-Feb-2015
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=acmesoft, OU=information resources department, O=certificate authority, L=toronto, ST=ontario, C=ca
Issuer: CN=acmesoft, OU=information resources department, O=certificate authority, L=toronto, ST=ontario, C=ca
Serial number: 381e5a1f
Valid from: Mon Feb 02 00:01:14 EST 2015 until: Sun May 03 01:01:14 EDT 2015
Certificate fingerprints:
 MD5:  94:A1:76:2F:D5:05:8D:3C:2C:0F:B2:07:EC:9A:1E:12
 SHA1: AD:0A:28:AD:D9:42:C8:B3:C7:7D:CB:36:6F:EF:2C:99:50:00:30:3C
 SHA256: 31:14:A0:F8:51:72:37:7C:F5:25:6C:3A:F3:10:74:D8:F8:2B:B8:BC:FE:C7:F3:56:89:00:C4:6B:36:48:B2:A4
 Signature algorithm name: SHA1withDSA
 Version: 3

*******************************************
*******************************************

Alias name: ME_signedby_acmesoft
Creation date: 11-Feb-2015
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=kim yap, OU=rbss, O=cibc, L=toronto, ST=ontario, C=ca
Issuer: CN=acmesoft, OU=information resources department, O=certificate authority, L=toronto, ST=ontario, C=ca
Serial number: 4ecdc79c
Valid from: Fri Jan 23 11:10:12 EST 2015 until: Thu Apr 23 12:10:12 EDT 2015
Certificate fingerprints:
 MD5:  AF:27:8B:63:86:A7:3F:FE:D9:03:64:3E:AB:7E:CE:DF
 SHA1: 2E:8A:78:ED:14:12:00:78:67:91:EE:8D:79:45:56:34:FC:17:02:FE
 SHA256: 28:60:A4:20:F1:7E:D3:3B:11:7E:D1:A1:04:F3:3C:70:43:92:91:16:CD:D6:96:A6:CC:71:94:10:1B:26:9D:09
 Signature algorithm name: SHA1withDSA
 Version: 3

Public Key: 02 81 80 79 14 21 28 57 EF 30 0D 98 0D 1A 8B EB 35 C3 76 06 0C FC DC D1 40 A6 0B 30 A4 F0 6E 24 AC 92 2D 44 F9 8F BB F9 51 6D 7F 99 F2 18 A4 55 2F D4 4A 1D 4F CC 9B 3D 5F 00 F6 95 58 77 E3 7E AD 2D 87 79 B7 9F BD 35 1D DC AF 7E 24 EC C7 09 20 C4 3D CA E6 5F 59 49 A9 00 DC 4B 06 CF 37 30 65 4E AC CB 80 50 F4 F4 21 8E DD 81 99 14 AA 9E 3A 07 C3 1B 2E 76 61 F9 B8 51 2A E0 A6 BA 55 0E DB 90 19
```

---

Here's the original except from the CoreJava 2 on Certificate Signing (simulating a CA) by Cay Horstmann.

In the section "Verifying a Signature " on page 814 , you saw how Alice used a selfsigned certificate to distribute a
public key to Bob. However, Bob needed to ensure that the certificate was valid by verifying the fingerprint with
Alice.
Suppose Alice wants to send her colleague Cindy a signed message, but Cindy doesn't want to bother with
verifying lots of signature fingerprints. Now suppose that there is an entity that Cindy trusts to verify signatures.
In this example, Cindy trusts the Information Resources Department at ACME Software.
That department operates a certificate authority (CA). Everyone at ACME has the CA's public key in their keystore,
installed by a system administrator who carefully checked the key fingerprint. The CA signs the keys of ACME
employees. When they install each other's keys, then the keystore will trust them implicitly because they are
signed by a trusted key.

Here is how you can simulate this process.
Create a keystore acmesoft.certs .
Generate a key par and export the public key:

Code View:
keytool -genkeypair -keystore acmesoft.certs -alias acmeroot
keytool -exportcert -keystore acmesoft.certs -alias acmeroot -file acmeroot.cer

The public key is exported into a "self-signed" certificate. Then add it to every employee's keystore.

Code View:
keytool -importcert -keystore cindy.certs -alias acmeroot -file acmeroot.cer

For Alice to send messages to Cindy and to everyone else at ACME Software, she needs to bring her certificate to
the Information Resources Department and have it signed. Unfortunately, this functionality is missing in the
keytool program. In the book's companion code, we supply a CertificateSigner class to fill the gap. An
authorized staff member at ACME Software would verify Alice's identity and generate a signed certificate as
follows:

java CertificateSigner -keystore acmesoft.certs -alias acmeroot
-infile alice.cer -outfile alice_signedby_acmeroot.cer

The certificate signer program must have access to the ACME Software keystore, and the staff member must know
the keystore password. Clearly, this is a sensitive operation.
Alice gives the file alice_signedby_acmeroot.cer file to Cindy and to anyone else in ACME Software.
Alternatively, ACME Software can simply store the file in a company directory. Remember, this file contains Alice's
public key and an assertion by ACME Software that this key really belongs to Alice.
Now Cindy imports the signed certificate into her keystore:

Code View:
keytool -importcert -keystore cindy.certs -alias alice -file alice_signedby_acmeroot.cer

The keystore verifies that the key was signed by a trusted root key that is already present in the keystore. Cindy is
not asked to verify the certificate fingerprint.
Once Cindy has added the root certificate and the certificates of the people who regularly send her documents, she
never has to worry about the keystore again.

Here's the code for the CertificateSigner program:

```
public class CertificateSigner
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String ksname = null; // the keystore name
  String alias = null; // the private key alias
  String inname = null; // the input file name
  String outname = null; // the output file name
  for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2)
  {
     if (args[i].equals("-keystore")) ksname = args[i + 1];
     else if (args[i].equals("-alias")) alias = args[i + 1];
     else if (args[i].equals("-infile")) inname = args[i + 1];
     else if (args[i].equals("-outfile")) outname = args[i + 1];
     else usage();
  }

  if (ksname == null || alias == null || inname == null || outname == null) usage();

  try
  {
     Console console = System.console();
     if (console == null) error("No console");
     char[] password = console.readPassword("Keystore password: ");
     KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS", "SUN");
     InputStream in = new FileInputStream(ksname);
     store.load(in, password);
     Arrays.fill(password, ' ');
     in.close();

     char[] keyPassword = console.readPassword("Key password for %s: ", alias);
     PrivateKey issuerPrivateKey = (PrivateKey) store.getKey(alias, keyPassword);
     Arrays.fill(keyPassword, ' ');

     if (issuerPrivateKey == null) error("No such private key");

            in = new FileInputStream(inname);

         CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

         X509Certificate inCert = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(in);
         in.close();
         byte[] inCertBytes = inCert.getTBSCertificate();

     X509Certificate issuerCert = (X509Certificate) store.getCertificate(alias);
     Principal issuer = issuerCert.getSubjectDN();
     String issuerSigAlg = issuerCert.getSigAlgName();

     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outname);

     X509CertInfo info = new X509CertInfo(inCertBytes);
     info.set(X509CertInfo.ISSUER, new CertificateIssuerName((X500Name) issuer));

     X509CertImpl outCert = new X509CertImpl(info);
     outCert.sign(issuerPrivateKey, issuerSigAlg);
     outCert.derEncode(out);

     out.close();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public static void error(String message)
 {
  System.out.println(message);
  System.exit(1);
 }

public static void usage()
{
  System.out.println("Usage: java CertificateSigner"
        + " -keystore keyStore -alias issuerKeyAlias"
        + " -infile inputFile -outfile outputFile");
  System.exit(1);
}
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Peter Gutmann has a very good book on [Engineering Security](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf). It includes a section on Code Signing. Java Code Signing is a somewhat bad example to study. Java mixes authentication (code signing) with authorization (ability to leave sandbox). Authentication does not mean authorization! Also see [Java’s Losing Security Legacy](http://threatpost.com/javas-losing-security-legacy).

Comment: @jww Thanks for your reply. I'm actually reading CoreJava Volume 2 by Cay Horstmann - on security topic. I'm trying to understand the certification cycle involving CA and code signing

Comment: The problem with explaining what you think you did instead showing the code (or the actual keystore contents and jarsigner command lines) is that a very common source of bugs is caused by typos, etc. so that you did not in fact do what you thought you did. Without this info we can't know what you actually did.

Comment: @GregS I've added the certficate signatures

Comment: @jww It's on-topic. It is basically about how to use the keytool correctly, a programming task since he is signing JAR files.

Comment: @ EJP - whatever... Everything (command, program, concept, HowTo) on a Linux distribution is on-topic because programmers use them in one way or another....

Comment: @jww In this case I have to agree with EJP although it is borderline off topic. This is required to setup a runtime environment, that should be on topic. Otherwise you cannot get the applications to run securely. That does not mean that everything else in a Linux distro is on topic.

Answer (score 1):

> Process 1 in chronological order
>
> me gives this ME signed_cert to cindy

No. ME imports this signed certificate into his keystore using the same alias.

> cindy import ME signed_cert trusted cert without issue since cindy already imported CA certificate earlier

No. Unnecessary.

> me signed the ME jar with ME private keys (not the ME signed_cert)

Correct, although the distinction is void because you just supply the alias, which covers both.

> me give the ME jar file to cindy
>   cindy does a jarsigner verify on ME jar

Correct.

> Process 1 issues
>   Cindy keystore would have the ME signed_certs which consists of ME public key and CA signature.

No. See above.

> The jarsigner verification on the ME jar on cindy.jks shows no key found.

Then you didn't sign it correctly. See above.

> I expected it show key found since the ME signed_cert in cindy.jks has ME public key with CA private signature and the ME jar file is signed with ME private key.

It doesn't need that. I don't know what you mean by 'key found', but Cindy won't have your private key, and doesn't need it to verify the JAR file. Actually she doesn't even need her own KeyStore for that. The certificate chain is in the JAR file.

> Process 2
>   Exactly as process 1 but:
>   Me import the returned ME signed_certs from acmesoft (which consists of > ME public key and CA signature) into ME jks
>   ME use jarsigner to sign the ME jar file
>
> Process 2 issues
>   Upon signing, the jarsigner complaints the following:
>
> jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: primary_root. primary_root must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.

You didn't import the signed certificate correctly. You have to use the same alias as you did when generating the keypair and CSR. That's the only way the signed certificate can be associated with the private key.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added the original excerpts from the CoreJava V2 - Certificate Sigining. This section does not use CSR but rather simulating a CA. Run through it and you will see exactly what i'm trying to achieve.